# Ember Array call get on the return on findBy returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, findby

This seems like it would be obvious.  I don't know where I'm going wrong.

in a controller, for the computed property:

```
totalMonthlyEsales: (->
  @findBy('key', 'value1')
).property('@each.answer')
```

I can ask for a property on this in my template fine.

```
<div>{{totalMonthlyEsales.answer}}</div>
```

returns "23424"

However if I try

```
totalMonthlyEsales: (->
  @findBy('key', 'value1').get('answer')
).property('@each.answer')
```

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined"
Ultimately I want to do something like

```
totalMonthlyEsales: (->
  parseInt @findBy('key', 'value1').get('answer')
).property('@each.answer')

plccDcSalesCash: (->
  parseInt @findBy('key', 'value2').get('answer')
).property('@each.answer')

otherTenderTypes: (->
  @get('plccDcSalesCash') - @get('totalMonthlyEsales')
).property('totalMonthlyEsales', 'plccDcSalesCash')
```

Comment: This belongs in Coffeescript?... It's like posting C++ under C because it's just C.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the content of the ArrayController is being populated asynchronously and though there ultimately ends up being a value returned by that computed property (that has an answer associated with it), when the computed property fires at first, there isn't a matching value, so it returns undefined and, of course, you can't call `.get()` on an undefined value. Since you're in coffeescript, you can just do this:

```
totalMonthlyEsales: (->
  @findBy('key', 'value1')?.get('answer')
).property('@each.answer')
```

The `?` says only attempt the method call if the value returned from `findBy()` is truthy.